# To make local variable a global variable

Tags: python-3.x

I try to figure out how to make local function variable a global one, so I could use it in other functions.

```
def question():
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()

    def check_question(n):
        if ask != 'yes':
            question()
        else:
            return ask

    m = check_question(ask)
    print (m)
    return m
question()


print(f'he said:  {m}')

def what():
    print(m)
```

Comment: Create the variable outside of a function makes it global in python

Comment: You are asking about variable `m`?

Comment: dont use mutable global variables

Comment: You already `return m`, so why don't you **use it**?

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* need a global variable here.

Your function *returns* a value -- which you can use, like this:

```
m = question()
print(f'he said: {m}')
```

As for your other function `what`, you can pass an input parameter to it when you call it, e.g. define it like this:

```
def what(m):
    print(m)
```

and call it like this:

```
what(m)
```

In general, avoid global variables when the problem is easily solved by using function arguments and return values.

Comment: The point is I don't want to call question(), I need get the returned m and make it global to be able used in other functions.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Your `question()` function would have to be *called* at some point in order to get input. The point of returning a value from a function (which is what you're already doing) is so that it can be used elsewhere -- including passing it to other functions as I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, inside your function, you must declare the variable as global before you assign a value to it like this:

```
m = ''
def question():
    global m
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()

    def check_question(n):
        if ask != 'yes':
            question()
        else:
            return ask

    m = check_question(ask)
    print (m)
    return m question()


print(f'he said:  {m}')

def what():
    print(m)
```

But as costaparas pointed out, there are better ways to do that than to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply do `global m`

```
def question():
    global m
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()

    def check_question(n):
        if ask != 'yes':
            question()
        else:
            return ask

    m = check_question(ask)
    print (m)
    return m
question()


print(f'he said:  {m}')

def what():
    print(m)
```